# Do not return value after catching exception while using Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, exception, aop, spring-aop

I am using Spring AOP for exception handling.
 I am using around advice as I want to log the input parameters.

My aspect method is like this:

```
public Object methodName(ProceedingJointPoint pjp){
  Object returnVal = null;
   try{
  returnVal = pjp.proceed();
 } catch(Throable t) {
   // Log exception 

 }
 return returnVal ;

}
```

The problem currently I am facing is : When the exception is occured I want to log the exception but I do not want to return null (returnval).  Is it possible?

In the normal scenario without AOP :  when some line in the method throws an Exception after that line , no other lines get executed. I want behaviour like that.

How can we ahieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good old checked exceptions, the Java design mistake that just keeps on biting.

Just rethrow the throwable:

```
public Object methodName(ProceedingJointPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

...

 try {
   return pjp.proceed();
 } catch (Throwable t) {
   // so something with t: log, wrap, return default, ...
   log.warn("invocation of " + pjp.getSignature().toLongString() + " failed", t);
   // I hate logging and re-raising, but let's do it for the sake of this example
   throw t;
 }
```

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5309945/116509

Comment: Is there any way to avoid returning without rethrowing?

Comment: Look at it this way: if you hadn't had an aspect here, the code would have thrown an exception. Your aspect shouldn't change that behaviour.

Comment: There is no theoretical way a method with a declared return value could terminate normally without returning a value. Just imagine what would the line of code that called your aspect look like.